# Generate list of numbers and their negative counterparts

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, array, integer

[A recent SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61348795/5306507) asks for *a convenient one-liner to generate a list of numbers and their negative counterparts in Python*.

Given two integers \$1≤a≤b\$, generate all the integers \$x\$ such that \$a≤|x|≤b\$. The result may be printed or returned in any order or structure, as putting the result into a list and sorting it, yields `[-b,1-b,2-b,…,-a,a,a+1,a+2,…,b]`

#### Examples

\$a=6,b=9\$ gives `[6,-6,7,-7,8,-8,9,-9]` or `[6,7,8,9,-9,-8,-7,-6]` or `[-8,7,-9,-7,9,8,-6,6]` or `[[6,-6],[7,-7],[8,-8],[9,-9]]` or `[[6,7,8,9],[-6,-7,-8,-9]]` etc.

\$a=6,b=6\$ gives `[6,-6]` or `[-6,6]` or `[[6,-6]]` or `[[6],[-6]]` etc.

Comment: [Semi-related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93441/print-all-integers)

Comment: Since you seemed to accept concatenated negative numbers in a comment to a certain answer, do you accept `1-1 2-2 3-3 4-4`?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate It wasn't just concatenated negative numbers. They were generated as proper numbers, and just printed individually with no separator. That's fine. However, I would object to using string operations to interleave spaces and dashes with duplicated digits, as the individual numbers are never generated then.

Comment: What about [languages that does not support negative numbers](http://esolangs.org/wiki/1+)?

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive Decide on a bit-width (minimally 8 bits) and use the corresponding unsigned integer. E.g. `-6` is `250`.

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive By the looks of that Hello world example it can print, so you could print the `-` characters manually?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen It's not allowed. "However, I would object to using string operations to interleave spaces and dashes with duplicated digits, as the individual numbers are never generated then." -- Adám

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 33 bytes

```python
def f(a,b):print-a,a;a<b<f(a+1,b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI1EnSdOqoCgzr0Q3USfROtEmyQYoqG0IFP6fpmGmY6n5HwA)

A recursive function that prints in a two-column format. Based on [ideas from Surculose Sputum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203803/20260).

In Python 3, we'd need 2 more bytes for `print()` needing parens.

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:range(a,b+1)+range(-b,1-a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8mqKDEvPVUDyNI21NSGcHSTdAx1EzX/FxRl5pUopGmY6VhqciE4Zpr/AQ)

Unfortunately for this challenge, Python's ranges are exclusive, so we have to add 1 to both upper endpoints.

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 21 bytes

```hs
a%b=[a..b]++[-b.. -a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E1yTY6UU8vKVZbO1o3SU9PQTcx9n9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCioKZgqqC5f9/yWk5ienF/3WTCwoA)

Looks like this boring solution is shortest. The space in before `-a` is needed to avoid a misparse with `..-`.

**22 bytes**

```hs
a%b=[id,(0-)]<*>[a..b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E1yTY6M0VHw0BXM9ZGyy46UU8vKfZ/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgoqCmYKqguX/f8lpOYnpxf91kwsKAA)

**22 bytes**

```hs
a%b=[[x,-x]|x<-[a..b]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E1yTY6ukJHtyK2psJGNzpRTy8pNvZ/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgoqCmYKqguX/f8lpOYnpxf91kwsKAA)

**23 bytes**

```hs
a%b=do x<-[a..b];[x,-x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E1yTYlX6HCRjc6UU8vKdY6ukJHtyL2f25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKgpmCqoLl/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

**23 bytes**

```hs
a%b=(,)<*>(0-)<$>[a..b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E1yVZDR9NGy07DQFfTRsUuOlFPLyn2f25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKgpmCqoLl/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
ŸD(«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6A4XjUOr//8347IEAA)

## Explanation

```
     Takes two input integers
Ÿ    Inclusive range.
 D   Duplicate the stack.
  (  Negate all items of the duplicated item.
   « Concatenate both lists.
     Implicit output
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
_BM}F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P97Jt9bt//9oUx1Dg1gA)

`}F` forms an inclusive range, then `_B` pairs a number with its negation, and `M` maps that over the list.

Comment: [`_MB}F`](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P97Xqdbt/38zHUsA) also works.

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 28 bytes

```
$args[0]..$args[1]|%{$_,-$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL042iBWTw/CMoytUa1WidfRVYmv/f//v9l/SwA)

`$args[0]..$args[1]` generates integer array range from `$args[0]` to `$args[1]`. It's piped and then each item in that array is mapped to itself and its negative counterpart.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and great first answer, Eligrhath! Just received your first upvote from me :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>40</s> 39 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @xnor!*

```python
f=lambda a,b:b//a*[0]and[a,-a]+f(a+1,b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIVEnySpJXz9RK9ogNjEvJTpRRzcxVjtNI1HbUCdJ839BUWZeiUaahpmOpaYmF4Jnpqn5HwA)

This would be 38 bytes in Python2, by replacing `//` operator with just `/`.

Comment: Huh, your solution is more competitive that I'd expected for anything recursive here. You can save a byte on the base case, two in Python 2: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIVEnySpJXz9RK9ogNjEvJTpRRzcxVjtNI1HbUCdJ839BUWZeiUaahpmOpabmfwA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @xnor Ah yes the list multiplication trick. Gotta keep that in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com), **19 bytes**

```
{(⊢,-)⍺,⍺(⊣+∘⍳-⍨)⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtE8wUqjUedS3S0dV81LtLB4iBvMXajzpmPOrdrPuodwVQeGutguX//wA)

Comment: Do you know TIO can auto-generate posts like this one? [Esc],[s],[g].

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and great first answer. Who'd have known you're already a very active member of APL Orchard before your first submission! Hope to continue to see you in the room :)

Comment: By the by, this format is also often used in APL TIO links, let me know what you think... I find it convenient for demonstrating all the input cases, when there are several: [Click me](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/TeFR2wSFao1HXYt0dDUf9e7SAWIgb7H2o44Zj3o36z7qXQEU3lr7/7@CmYJCmoKCJReUYcZ1aL0piHVovRGQaQwWNAEA) Even in the case of one input, it can be rather attractive: [Peekaboo](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/TeFR2wSFao1HXYt0dDUf9e7SAWIgb7H2o44Zj3o36z7qXQEU3lr7/7@ZQpqCJQA)

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful encouragement.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
rNƬ
```

A dyadic Link accepting two integers (either way around) which yields a list of two lists.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/I79ia////m/23BAA)**

#### How?

```
rNƬ - Link: integer, a; integer b                         e.g. 7; 4
r   - inclusive range  [a..b]                                  [7,6,5,4]
  Ƭ - collect up while unique, applying:
 N  -   negate (vectorises)                    0-applications: [[7,6,5,4]]
                                               1-application:  [[7,6,5,4],[-7,-6,-5,-4]]
                                               2-applications: [[7,6,5,4],[-7,-6,-5,-4],[7,6,5,4]]
                                                               - no longer distinct
                                                            -> [[7,6,5,4],[-7,-6,-5,-4]]
```

---

There are many, many ways to achieve this task in four bytes in Jelly.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, <s>76</s> <s>56</s> <s>52</s> 50 bytes

```java
b->a->{for(;a<=b;)System.out.println(a+","+-a++);}
```

-22 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

Takes the inputs in reverse order. Prints pairs of positive and negative integers `"a,-a"` newline separated.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dY8xa8MwEIV3/4rDk4xtjYHWiZdCIUPIkLF0ODlykCPLwjoFQvBvdxVXpR3c5bjHvXf3XYc3LLvzdW40OgcHVOaRADhCUg10Yco9Kc1bbxpSg@HvsdnuDcmLHIs109tgnO/l@GOqa2hhN4uyxrJ@tMPIKtzuRJWd7o5kzwdP3I7KkDYM87RI8xLzPKumuUoCjfVCB5oIdRvUGfoAyk4UMpePT8DsCQ1A0hHbFC9Z9VduFjklv38tK5ZpuAlYPKuIO1aQ0r2xnl4hzcUCFxCDiEfW/EdP34HoaTlaq@9MZBybRlpi@H860k7zFw)

**Explanation:**

```java
b->a->{                  // Method with two integer parameters and no return-type
  for(;a<=b;)            //  Loop in the range [a,b]:
    System.out.println(  //   Print with trailing newline:
      a                  //    `a`
      +" "               //    appended with a space
      +-a                //    appended with `-a`
         ++);}           //   And then increase `a` by 1 with `a++`
```

Comment: Don't know if fully valid, but [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##lZA9b4MwEIZ3fsWJyZbBY6TWgbFqJTJlrDocxKSmxFj2mSqK@O2UINRm7XLf7ys91@GIeXf6mpseQ4ADGntLAAIhmQa6ZSsjmV620TZkBitftmL/Zkmftc/@e3RA9zveclmW0EIx13mJeXkb0UNVWP39oHrF8LkoGVft4JnCfVErXkkXiWGWoxBceU3RW6jUNKtkYXCx7heGDWUczAkuCx47kjf2/P4ByO@oAKQDsV32xNVju1vbKfn7xmqxbo0lwOwe683jeA2kL3KIJN1iT71ltUizVKBInyEVrUTn@iur@VYg3/yn@Qc)

Comment: Or [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##jY8xa8MwEIV3/4pDk41sjYFWscdCh0wZQ4eTYwc5imykkyEE/3ZXdgXt2OV4j3e8@27AGavhel9bg97DCbV9ZQCekHQLQ0xFIG1EH2xLerTiI4njp6Xu1rnyf0tnctremgZ6qFdVNVg1rxkd@Jox2Y8ul3islSw8r5EzYLxCzmFT0nUUnAUvl1VmkW0KykS2hDiP@gqPiJ3/nLh8ARbbCwDUecoP5Vsh/9rDbpfs98u9Yk@1JcBymyp1nJ@euocYA4kp1pOxueKsZDxSvkfMXuA0mWeuiiSwSP3L@g0).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah nice, I hadn't thought about just printing directly.. And an additional -1 by removing that space at `+++` and -3 by printing directly. I like that Map approach as well btw, very original. :D

Comment: If you take the print route, [take it entirely](https://tio.run/##bY8xa8MwEIV3/4rDk4RsjYHWiZdCIUOmjG2HkyMHObJsrFMgBP92VzEqLSXLcce7e@@7Dq9YdqfL0lj0Hg5o3D0D8IRkGuiiKgMZK9vgGjKDk@@p2e4d6bOeimdLb4PzodfTz1JdQwu7RZU1lvW9HSZW4XanKn68edK9HALJcTKOrGMo8k@XixKF4NW8VFnEGYOyESdRXQdzgj6SsiPFo/PHFyB/UAOQ9sQ2xQuv/o6bdZyz38dWi1WNoYDFo6rk8Z@JKZEXuYhcr5An41biONobU1xi0@iRGCblyUcpfV6@AQ)! ;-) I used `\n` for consistency because of a comment to the question. But one more byte can be gained if you keep the space.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah nice. :) And space or comma should be fine. OP even allows [this kind of output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203797/generate-list-of-numbers-and-their-negative-counterparts/203813?noredirect=1#comment483726_203802).

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>44</s> <s>43</s></sup> 42 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to [S.S. Anne](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/89298/s-s-anne)!!!

```c
f(a,b){for(;b/a;)printf("-%d %1$d ",a++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1EnSbM6Lb9IwzpJP9Fas6AoM68kTUNJVzVFQdVQJUVBSSdRW1vTuvZ/bmJmnoZmNVeahpmOpaY1F0xlTJ4SkAcSNQPStf8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 22 bytes

```
->a,b{[*-b..-a,*a..b]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cuUSepOlpLN0lPTzdRRytRTy8ptvZ/gUJatJmOZex/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <strike>26</strike> 25 bytes

-1 bytes thanks to Giuseppe

```r
function(a,b)c(a:b,-b:-a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jUSdJM1kj0SpJR1cjySpRU/N/moaZjpkmF4iy1PwPAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-pn` , 5 bytes

```
ɧ⑷④±.
```

It prints all the numbers separated by newlines.

### Explained

```
ɧ⑷④±.
ɧ      # Generate a range between the two implicit inputs
 ⑷④±. # For each number in that range, print it raw without popping, negate it, and print it raw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARkA5v9rZWf//8mn4pG34pGjwrEu//82Cjn/LXBu)

Comment: The challenge says you may print it in any structure, so [this](https://tio.run/##ARgA5/9rZWf//8mn4pG34pGjwrH//zYKOf8tcG4) is probably okay.

Comment: @petStorm It is.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [@mypronounismonicareinstate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36445/my-pronoun-is-monicareinstate).

```javascript
b=>f=a=>a>b?[]:[a,-a,...f(a+1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9u@z/J1i7NNtHWLtEuyT461io6UUc3UUdPTy9NI1HbUDP2f3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RrqGpaaGmabmfwA)

Comment: As far as I see, the outermost parentheses aren't necessary (or are they for some reason?)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate thanks for noticing, coming from Python, I just assumed they needed to be there.

Comment: Is the `...` necessary?

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>47</s> 46 bytes

Much shorter than the beautiful LINQ solutions with `SelectMany` :(
I also cannot remember when I last wrote a `for` loop while code-golfing, so I likely missed trivial golfs.

```cs
a=>b=>{for(int i=a;i<=b;Print(-i++))Print(i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXoqPgmFySmZ8HYtvZKbgp2P5PtLVLsrWrTssv0gAKKmTaJlpn2tgmWQcUAbkaupna2pqaEHampnXtf2suNw0zTQ1LTev/AA)

Comment: You can get rid of `i` in the `for` loop. You can also combine the `print`s. Should be valid according to the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 66 bytes

```
=ArrayFormula({Row(Indirect(A1&":"&A2));-Row(Indirect(A1&":"&A2))}
```

Sheets will automatically add the last closing parentheses when you exit the cell. (A 1.5% byte reduction!)

Input is in cells A1 and A2. The order doesn't actually matter.
`Indirect(A1&":"&A2)` creates a range that contains all the rows between those numbers, inclusive.
`Row(Indirect(~))` returns the row numbers of everything in that range.
`{Row(~);-Row(~)}` creates an array of the positive and negative row numbers.
`ArrayFormula(~)` makes all the other bits operate on and return arrays. Without this, it would only return the first value in the array (the first row number) instead of all of them.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>51</s> <s>46</s> 40 bytes

```php
fn($a,$b)=>[range($a,$b),range(-$b,-$a)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSZvs/LU9DJVFHJUnT1i66KDEvPRXK1YFwdFWSdHRVEjVj/1tzlSUWxaeU5hZoqKRpmOlYamqiC5kBhf4DAA)

simply using php7 lambda functions short notation and built-in array functions..

EDIT: hum I see that from PHP7.4 we have now a spread operator! -5 bytes

EDIT2: thanks to DomHastings for saving another 6 bytes!

Comment: Based on the accepted examples, I think you can drop the spreads entirely for -6!

Comment: @DomHastings Oh, yep! Hadn't even looked at the examples :D I was glad to use this new stuff though

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Core utilties, 21 bytes

```bash
seq $1 $2;seq -$2 -$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UEHFUEHFyBrE0lUxAmLD////m/23BAA)

Answer (score 2):

## LaTeX, <s>61</s> 56 bytes

```latex
\input tikz.tex\def\f#1#2{\foreach~in{#1,...,#2}{~;-~;}}
```

Defines a macro `f` that takes input as two arguments and outputs the numbers as tokens to latex (so they are printed in the pdf), semicolon-seperated.

### Explanation

```latex
\input tikz.tex                % load the tikz package for the foreach command
\def\f#1#2{                    % define a macro f that takes two arguments
   \foreach ~                  % loop with the loop variable called ~
                               % (to save a space between the name and "in")
   in {#1,...,#2} {            % where ~ ranges from the first to the second 
                               % argument, inclusive
        ~;-~;                  % the macro f expands to
                               % ~
                               % a semicolon and a minus sign
                               % ~
                               % another semicolon
   }
}
```

### Example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\input tikz.tex
\def\f#1#2{\foreach~in{#1,...,#2}{~;-~;}}
\begin{document}
\f6 9

\f6 6
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: 56 bytes by using `\input tikz.tex` and looping over `~` instead of `\,`: `\input tikz.tex\def\f#1#2{\foreach~in{#1,...,#2}{~ -~ }}`

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org) , 22 bytes

```
{a,b->(a..b)+(-b..-a)}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `W`, 3 bytes

```
ṡ:N
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=W&code=%E1%B9%A1%3AN&inputs=6%0A9&header=&footer=)

```
ṡ:N
ṡ       Inclusive range of inputs
 :      Duplicate
  N     Negate the duplicate

W flag: Wrap both ranges into one list, which is implicitly output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 36 bytes

```erlang
g(A,B)->[[X,-X]||X<-lists:seq(A,B)].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy3KScxL100tTi7KLCj5z/U/XcNRx0lT1y46OkJHNyK2pibCRjcns7ik2Ko4tRAsF6v3PzcxM08jOlZTQdeOSwEIMvOtyosyS1I10jXMdMw0NXWAAnk5Gpo6mLKWCFm9/wA)

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 40 bytes

Port of Surculose Sputum's answer.

```erlang
g(A,A)->[A,-A];g(A,B)->[A,-A]++g(A+1,B).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy3KScxL100tTi7KLCj5z/U/XcNRx1FT1y7aUUfXMdYaxHWCc7W1gXxtQ6CI3v/cxMw8jehYTQVdOy4FIMjMtyovyixJ1UjXMNMx09TUAQrk5Who6mDKWiJk9f4DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 24 bytes

```
&00p&v
0g-k@>::.'-,.1+:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X83AoECtjMsgXTfbwc7KSk9dV0fPUNvK4P9/QyMFMwA)

#### Explanation

`&00p&` is the input part. `&00p` takes \$b\$ as input and stores it in the top left corner. `&` takes input \$a\$ and pushes it to the stack.

`0g-k@>::.'-,.1+:0` is the main loop and, as the instruction pointer wraps around, equivalent to:

```
::.'-,.1+:00g-k@

::                duplicate a twice
  .               print a
   '-,            print '-'
      .           print a
       1+         increase a
         :        duplicate the new value of a
          00g     get b from the top-left corner
             -    calculate a-b, as Befunge has no negative values,
                  this is 0 for b>=a
              k@  execute *quit* (b-a)-times
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 17 bytes

```perl6
{$^a..$^b X*-1,1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1olLlFPTyUuSSFCS9dQx7D2vzUXV3FipUKahpmOgqWmNYJjpmn9HwA)

Just performs a multiplication (`*`) with every combination (`X`) of the range given (`$^a..$^b`) by -1 and 1

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 10 bytes

```
]-.&i:<:@[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Y3X11DKtbKwcov9rcilwpSZn5CuYKaQpWHL9BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Codepage)

```
mSe_…
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Pzc4Nf5Rw7L///@b/bcEAA)

Or alternatively:

```
Svm_…
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P7gsN/5Rw7L///@b/bcEAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
    …  # Create a an inclusive range using the two (implicit) input-arguments
m      # Map over this list
 Se    # and pair each element with:
   _   #  Its negative
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)

    …  # Create a an inclusive range using the two (implicit) input-arguments
 v     # Concatenate it with:
S m    #  The same list with each value mapped to:
   _   #   Its negative
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 11 bytes

```
ps^pr@Jng.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/oDiuoMjBKy9dT/v/f2MFSwA)

I feel like there's probably a better way to parse the input, but I'm not getting it. Explanation:

```
ps^p          # Parse input as block and split block to stack
    r@        # Generate range between two inputs
      Jng     # Duplicate and negate
         .+   # Concatenate and implicitly output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 15 bytes

```
{1 -1*/:y,y^!x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82q2lBB11BL36pSpzJOsaL2f1q0mbVl7H8A)

Comment: Why does `{1 -1*,y,y^!x}` not work?

Comment: @Adám K needs instructions (eahright) how to multiply, since the length of both args do not match. Multiplication (as many of the verbs) is right-atomic - it penetrates in depth to the levels of the nesting of the right argument.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what "right-atomic" means. I just thought that for a scalar function, if one side had one element and the other many, it'd extend the single argument.

Comment: @Adám Hmm, [as it seems](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok/blob/gh-pages/docs/Manual.md) `*` is fully atomic. In our case I'm multiplying a list of length 2 (1 -1) by a list of length 4 (9 6 7 8). I'm not sure why does `'` (each) not work here.

Comment: Each-ing with lists of two different lengths is always a length error.

Comment: @Adám Yes, it tries to pair-up the items.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107092/discussion-between-adam-and-galen-ivanov).

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 36 bytes

```
,[->+>->-<<<],+[->>+<<]>>[-<.+>>.-<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ1rXTttO107XxsYmVkcbyLPTBrLs7KJ1bfS07ez0dG1i//9n4wQA)

### Clarification

Input and output are treated as bytes (as permitted in [Can numeric input/output be in the form of byte values?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-the-form-of-byte-values/4719#4719))

Since negative bytes don't really make sense, a negative answer wraps around and starts at the largest value of the cell. For example, given a cell size of 128, the output for the input in bytes `[6, 9]` will be (in bytes) `[6,(128-6),7,(128-7),8,(128-8),9,(128-9)]`

Hopefully that's a fair enough interpretation of the rules!

Comment: i.e. your bytes should be interpreted as [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representations of signed integers.  If BF can only actually do I/O in unsigned decimal, that seems fine to me.  In assembly language there are no types, it's all just bytes, so it's up to the programmer to to write code that uses signed operations / comparisons on those bytes as opposed to float or unsigned compares.  (Many operations other than compare are the same for signed 2's complement vs. unsigned binary integers; division, right shift, and widening mul being different.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 20 bytes

```perl
say"$_
-$_"for<>..<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJJJZ5LVyVeKS2/yMZOT8/G7v9/My7Lf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 17 bytes

```sh
echo {,-}{$1..$2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanxPzU5I1@hWke3tlrFUE9Pxaj2vyYXV5qCoYIJkDRTsASTZv8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 22 bytes

1 byte more than Bash+seq, 5 bytes more than Zsh due to `eval`

```bash
eval echo {,-}{$1..$2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifpqGp8T@1LDFHITU5I1@hWke3tlrFUE9Pxaj2vyYXV5qCoYIJkDRTsASTZv8B)

Answer (score 1):

## Piet, 90 codels

Did someone say "one-liner"?

[image: Piet solution at codel size 1]

Okay, so technically it's *three* lines, but I couldn't figure out how to exit a Piet program in less than three pixels of width (or how to loop in less than two pixels). Here it is with a codel size of 4:

[image: Piet solution at codel size 4]

And here's the npiet trace of it processing \$a=6, b=9\$:

[image: Piet solution traced in npiet]

For input, it takes \$b\$ then \$a\$. For output, it calculates each value of \$x\$ and \$-x\$, outputting them without separators (as was allowed in a comment, as long as the individual numbers are actually calculated).

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-s`, 6 bytes

```
-Pa\,b
```

Outputs the positive numbers on one line and the negative numbers on the next. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fNyAxRifpP5BR/N/svyUA)

#### Explanation

```
        a and b are command-line args (implicit)
  a\,b  Inclusive range from a to b
 P      (printed)
-       Negate each value in the range
        Autoprint (implicit)
```

The `-s` flag puts a space between consecutive numbers in a list. Other options include `-n` (newline) and `-p` (output like `[6;7;8;9]`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 22 bytes

```
[ [a,b] dup vneg zip ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVeUmJeeWqyQnVqUl5oDESpLBakqVkgsLs5PLlYoKEotKaksKMrMK1Gw5uIyU7AEYrP/0QrRiTpJsQoppQUKZXmp6QpVmQUKsUBhPYVYheT83IL84lQFo6RMh/8A)

- `[a,b]` Make a range from the inputs (for example, `3 6`), inclusive.

  **Stack:** `T{ range f 3 4 1 }` (A virtual sequence that starts at 3, has 4 elements, and has an increment of 1.)
- `dup` Duplicate.

  **Stack:** `T{ range f 3 4 1 } T{ range f 3 4 1 }`
- `vneg` Flip the sign of every element in a sequence.

  **Stack:** `T{ range f 3 4 1 } { -3 -4 -5 -6 }`
- `zip` Combine two sequences into an associative mapping.

  **Stack:** `{ { 3 -3 } { 4 -4 } { 5 -5 } { 6 -6 } }`

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 63 bytes

```python
lambda n,l=[]:([l.extend([i,-i])for i in range(1,n+1)]+[l])[-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBCoAgDADQX9lRUQPpFvQlYwdDq8GaIR3q69d79/ecXWczKddWC2iUFWlxKFN7n6bVIcfE5Pc@gIEVRtGjuRw1ZE8BhTymTGY/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 7 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 5.76 bytes

```
1+:DnA+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLDbWtXPIctSE8qOCi6NjFllxmEA4A) Takes input as \$b\$ then \$a\$.

**Explanation:**

```python
1+:DnA+  # Implicit input
1+       # Add one to b (because of how Thunno's range works)
  :      # range from a to b+1
   Dn    # Duplicate and negate the top copy
     A+  # Concatenate the two lists
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 60 bytes

```go
func(a,b int)(o[]int){for;a<=b;a++{o=append(o,a,-a)};return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY0xDsIgGEZ3ToGdIKW6NRrKHbobh78VGqIFQsCF9CQuxMRD9Ta22sXp5Q3f-56vweZ556C_wSDxCNogPTrrw75QYygQeoDHSrxjUNVxblQ0PQHWYW0CJfZ8WZmU9Rwa0XEoy2QFOCfNlVgGrAI6cS9D9GbaGoe18X0iFCfU-iVxN0SRmp0o_fN68W2W848f)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 4 bytes

```
ŘĐ~Ž
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6IwjE@qO7v3/35TLCAA)

```
Ř         2 implicit inputs (larger, then smaller); get Řange between the two
 Đ        Đuplicate
  ~       Negate
   Ž      Žip the two lists together; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 15 bytes

```julia
a^b=[-b:-a;a:b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/PzEuyTZaN8lKN9E60Sop9r9DcUZ@uYJZnCUXjGX2HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `O`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
IßṄ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kr9S7IKlpSVpuhbLPA_Pf7izZUlxUnIxVGjBYjMuSwgTAA)

##### Explanation

```python
IßṄ  # Implicit input
I    # Inclusive range
 ß   # Print without popping
  Ṅ  # Negate each
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
Ｆ…·ＮＮＩ⟦ι±ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzMvOae0OLMsNSgxLz0VyC0oLfErzU1KLdLQ1FFA4WoqBBRl5pVoOCcWl2hEZ@oo@KWmJ5akamRqxmpqWv//b6Zg@V@3LAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ…·ＮＮ
```

Loop over the inclusive range between the two inputs.

```
Ｉ⟦ι±ι
```

Output each number and its negation as a string.

Answer (score 0):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

Port of my 05AB1E answer.

```
G,▌▲
```

Uncompressed:

```
.:_r+
```

## Explanation

```
.     % Inclusive range
 :    % Duplicate the operand
  _r  % Map by negation
    + % Concatenate
```

Comment: The github link in title is broken though.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Can you see [this](https://github.com/Random-People/w) repository?

Comment: Yes. 

Comment: Why'd you delete your other GitHub account? Is there something wrong with a'_' or a-ee? I would think that there's a lot of broken links out there.

Comment: @S.S.Anne My GH account got flagged, and it may seem like it is deleted. Don't worry, the repositories are all there.

Comment: You should report it and have it fixed. Why would it have been flagged?

Answer (score 0):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 47 bytes

```
procedure f(a,b)
write(c:=a to b," ",-c)&\z
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0zOz/v/v6AoPzk1pbQoVSFNI1EnSZOrvCizJFUj2co2UaEkXyFJR0lBSUc3WVMtpoorNS8FSX1uYmaehiaXAhCkaZjpWGqC5QE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 16 bytes

```
{a=Range@##,-a}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277vzrRNigxLz3VQVlZRzexVu1/QFFmXomCQ3q0mY5lLBcSzyz2/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 49 bytes

```
: f ( a b -- r r ) [a,b] >array dup [ neg ] map ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY0xC8IwFIR3f8WNCjajYAqu0qWLOJUOr@lLFGsSX9Khvz6GcnDDB/edJZODlOej6@8aHxbPC76UX3spIe84gURoS0j8W9mbCqJwzluUt89oD12vYcLMLiy2aFgcQZjQNJCaEwY6TyNuuwXzGjHAs8NYPyLacsG1bhRU@QM)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

Why doesn't MathGolf have a ranged list (nor negate) builtin?.. :/

```
kk↨ÞmÉ_~)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z87@1HbisPzcg93xtdp/v9vpmDJZaZgBgA)

Or alternatively:

```
╒_b*^k({╞
```

Takes the inputs in reverse order.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1EnxSVpx2RrVj6bO@//fUsGMy0zBDAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
kk         # Push both input-integers explicitly (since there seems to be a bug with `↨`..)
  ↨        # Loop the first integer amount of times, 
           # and create a list in the range of the two integers every iteration :S
           # (i.e. 6 9 will loop 6 times, creating a list [6,7,8,9] every iteration)
   Þ       #  In every iteration: leave just the top item of the stack
    m      #  And map it to,
     É     #  using the following 3 commands:
      _    #   Duplicate the current integer
       ~   #   Take the bitwise-NOT: -a-1
        )  #   And increase it by 1 to make it -a
           # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)

╒          # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 _         # Duplicate it
  b*       # Multiply each inner value by -1
    ^      # Zip the two lists together, creating pairs
     k(    # Push the second input-integer, and decrease it by 1
       {   # Loop that many times:
        ╞  #  And discard the first item of the list every iteration
           # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 18 bytes

```
=A#|2B-2A+2&-Z,Y+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/39ZRucbISdfIUdtITTdKJ1Lb8P9/MwVLAA)

### Explanation

```
                     A = first input
                     B = second input
=A                   first term in sequence = A
  #|2B-2A+2          n = 2(B - A + 1)
           &         output first n terms in sequence
            -Z,      alternate the negative of the previous term
               Y+1     and two terms ago + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 25 bytes

```
?[d0r-np1-rd3Rd3R!>L]dsLx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98@OsWgSDevwFC3KMU4CIgU7XxiU4p9Kv7/N1OwBAA)

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(a,b):
print(-a,a)
if(a<b):
    f(a+1,b)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf. What language is this? Look at the other answers to see how to format your post.

Answer (score 0):

## x86-64 machine code function, 11 bytes

Callable with `int *dst` in RDI, `int low` in ESI, and `int high` in EAX.
Returns a pointer to one-past-the-end of the sequence in RDI.

```
     4                         posneg_seq:
     8                         .loop:                ; do{
     9 00000000 AB                 stosd               ; *dst++ = a
    10 00000001 F7D8               neg  eax            ; a = -a
    11 00000003 AB                 stosd               ; *dst++ = a
    12 00000004 F7D0               not  eax            ; a = -a - 1
    13 00000006 39F0               cmp  eax, esi
    14 00000008 7DF6               jge .loop         ; }while(a>=low);
    15                         
    19 0000000A C3                 ret
```

(Line numbers are discontiguous because I trimmed lines with %ifdeffed out code to adapt the calling convention to x86-64 System V for testing with a C++ caller: `xchg eax, edx` at the start, `mov  rax, rdi` at the end.)

This is interesting in x86 asm because we have an efficient `*dst++ = eax` that only works for one register.  So not only would it take extra instructions to get `-a` in another register, it would take more bytes to store it.

The trick is to fold the increment (or decrement) into the negation using **[the 2's complement identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278518/how-to-prove-that-the-c-statement-x-x1-and-x-1-yield-the-same-results) `-x - 1 == ~x`** to flip back to positive and decrement with a NOT instruction.  NEG/NOT gives us `x -= 1` overall, with access to `-x` along the way.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVTdb9owEH8mf8WJSGv4aoFpk0YAadrz9rJHiirXviSejO3ZDmWr@rezs4MKbTVpmh@S3Pl3v/sOt3ZSc3484iGg09D/0gepAwyt8RrrO48/iyTft9U43Sjz0H00sm4GZZbd3ECtzD1T4LmxCMzvwAcWcIeEktoHZAJMBR4tc6SHb5@/fwVvWscRKqkwI5Mi618TK6o7/0sHdgBtrMNKHm51n66iBwXnoJL2LC6SDK/OgTc1IDuMAcUBIM9z4EwpqWvgRu8pPGk0MMEs5Q6dI2WMXbwmykGYR3j24YPx4g1kKHwYjWAF7Iyk8CBG8BLJCDRh/8Vnwt/5JjA7I/nOwil3L8/qHzVCyvHC/OmhoSYUbL2i3g7KBH5TzJ3ZA7jI54T8t1pGM4fhVFgWwqm1UR6Ux1xqrlqBsJTGB4dst87OOh@EkvfXzaWOqdo4GRoCZnECd0zqNJ3M1XwMvGFuOKTv/QAes95pWKk2H8dpWFefStJWUET4evU@oXoREoscjIwX@81sS1Pd60WLF/p50j9lWc/L33gXIL4IUUTkJJZuOIcRfCg717Qwm4jYlrQhz5rZdEoKoghisaDZV0VaLHqMIngMMzpzOtQHWixrpDc66xiHqAX5u9jMZJsW8rSMOaU3zXqVcVBQWzyVpg3mHSAsog/KmHpCvA@NURg1FTrKNUXDTRtguSQsPa5u9VXKNkfl8cTY/RgoBDIswS5jPPQereaJmHhbHwciNBgb3zqNAiLIhjde7Ga67RyFq06ebV851kJW2dPxDw) with a C++ test caller (and the asm wrapped in an inline-asm statement at global scope, with extra instructions to adapt the calling convention).

Output is in decreasing magnitude, like  `9, -9, 8, -8, 7, -7, 6, -6`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>30</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
$[x,y][++x..y(0-x)..0-y]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?gKVju0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$6\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 4.939 bytes

```
Rx}
wN
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJSeH1cbndOIiwiNlxuNyJd)

```
Rx} # Line 1
Rx  # Range from a
  } # To b + 1
----------
wN  # Line 2. Takes the result of the above line as input
 N  # Negate the range
w   # Wrap in a list with the original range
```