# Print all Polynomials

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, polynomials

The set of all polynomials with **integer** coefficients is countable.
This means that there is a sequence that contains each polynomial with integer coefficients exactly once.

Your goal is it to write a function or program that outputs such a sequence.

Example (you may use another sequence):

```
// list of integers [i -> Z(i)] : 0,1,-1,2,-2,...
// integer -> polynomial
// 1. factor index n=product_i p_i^k_i
// 2. return polynomial sum_i Z(k_i)*x^(i-1)
1 -> 0     // all powers 0 -> all summands 0
2 -> 1     // 2^1 -> 1*x^0
3 -> x     // 3^1 -> 1*x^1
4 -> -1    // 2^2 -> -1*x^0
5 -> x²    // 5^1 -> 1*x^2
6 -> x+1   // 2^1*3^1 -> 1*x^0+1*x^1
7 -> x³    // 7^1 -> 1*x^3
8 -> 2     // 2^3 -> 2*x^0
9 -> -x    // 3^2 -> -1*x^1
...
```

For ideas how to compute the sequence of all integers see [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93441/print-all-integers)

Rules:

- Each integer polynomial has to (eventually) appear in the sequence generated by your program
- Polynomials are **not** allowed to appear more than once
- The standard sequence [IO-rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info) apply
- You may output polynomials as lists of coefficients
- Using the empty string/list to represent zero is allowed
- You are allowed to output the coefficients in reverse order (constant coefficient on the left)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest program (per language) wins.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: May we output coefficients in the opposite order, with constant term on the left?

Comment: Are we allowed to use the empty string to represent zero as a coefficient within a list of coefficients, e.g. `1,,2` to represent `1*x^2+0*x+2`?

Comment: @DLosc I will not override the default format for numbers. This means that the [empty string can **only** be used to represent zero](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8395/is-the-empty-string-an-acceptable-decimal-representation-of-0) **if it is your languages natural representation for zero**.

Comment: @bsoelch That makes sense. Figured it wouldn't hurt to ask. :)

Answer (score 11):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 56 bytes

```python
P=[[0]]
for*t,h in P:print(P[-1]);P+=t+[h,0],t+[(h<1)-h]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P8A2OtogNpYrLb9Iq0QnQyEzTyHAqqAoM69EIyBa1zBW0zpA27ZEOzpDxyBWB0hrZNgYaupmxP7/DwA)

Prints lists indefinitely as polynomials reversed. The idea is that every nonempty list of integers is generated uniquely by repeatedly applying one of two operations starting from the singleton `[0]`:

1. Append a `[0]`
2. Advance the last element `h` via the map `h -> (h<=0)-h`, which walks through the integers as `0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, ...`.

We do a breadth-first walk on this infinite binary tree to generate all these lists. To do this, we keep a list `P` of nodes to explore starting with just the root `[0]`, iterate over it, and when we explore a node `l`, we append to `P` the two children of `l`.

Note that branch (1) creates the lists with a trailing 0 and branch (2) creates all those starting with any other value. So, outputting just the branch (2) nodes gives all nonzero polynomials represented without extra trailing zeroes. We do this by repeatedly printing the last element of `P` after doing the append which puts the branch (2) result last. By also doing this print at the start, we also output the zero polynomial at the root of `P`, which we'd otherwise miss.

*Thanks to loopy walt for -1 byte by flipping the order and Jonathan Allan
for -1 from not using `<=`.*

Comment: Nice one! You can save one, trivially, by reversing the order of representation. I.e. use `for*t,h in` etc.

Comment: This is a nice method! `h<1` saves one.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 75 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s*[0]and[s%-2^r(s//4)]+f(r(s//2))
r=lambda s:s and s%2^2*r(s//4)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3vdNscxJzk1ISFYqtirWiDWIT81Kii1V1jeKKNIr19U00Y7XTNMBMI01NriIkxQpAlQrFqkZxRlpQpVAjfdPyixQU8hQy8xSKEvPSUzVMDDStCooy80o00jTygKZA2DmpeRrVWrmJBRolpQU5qTogVpoORIehARBoamrWakINhbkXAA)

^^^
Version without string intermediates.

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 48 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i:n and(n>>2**i-1&1)-2*f(n>>2*2**i,i)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY9BCoMwEEX3OcWsSkZUtHRRBF16CZGSYqIBnYQQKaX0JN100257nt6mEVs6q8_M_Pdnbk979oOh-_0xe5Xs35kqRzEdOwEU64JAUMepqrZRpJN8k2OyjdTaWFqxxq_v1UkFNScsGBgooQlbYQrKONCgCZygXnJKj9ofRkm9Hzhiy-A06FEGSwgC0yR5W5ZZYIBJrbEcGTjpZ0dgGFtY9GftMiys0-T5kots1YHNL9EkLPezHWW8qDpeHXkWChGv-D379_YH)

^^^
This one may be illegal: It takes enumeration index and coefficient index and returns only that coefficient.

Uses @Bubbler's negabinaries instead of my previous method.

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 107 bytes

```python
lambda n:g(f"{n:b}"[::-1])or[0]
g=lambda s:"1"in s and[-(s[0]>"0")^int("0"+s[2::2][::-1],2)]+g(s[1::2])or[]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1BCoMwEEX3PUXIKlMVjKsSsDfoCWwKEU0q1VGMLop4km6E0t6pt2lCnM18_vz_5vUdntO9x-2t8-tnnnRy-j1a1ZWVIigM03RBUa60ECLhEvqxSOXB5HvCCsppg8QShVWRMOuuZ5pSuDU4MSciW2RCZDLU4wxkZFyKe8_D5P7yovuRECSONSo0NctSEMPoKZohwCHotka2HDs1sGke2jr2SsehwVM3ALACBOi2hf0H)

If representing the 0 polynomial by the empty list is acceptable, we can save 5 as @JonathanAllan points out.

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 102 bytes

```python
lambda n:g(f"{n:b}"[::-1])
g=lambda s:"1"in s and[-(s[0]>"0")^int("0"+s[2::2][::-1],2)]+g(s[1::2])or[]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1BCoMwEEX3niJklakK6qoE7A16gjSFiCYVdAxRF0U8STdCae_U2zQSZzOPmflvXl_7nB4Dbm9d3j7zpNPzT3eqr2pFkBum6YK8WqngPM0lRKY8liOnOW2RjERhLVI2ikxeaEbh3uLEPMSjKDgvZEgmBcjY-Kt8n8HghDy-XfXgCEHiXU6haViRAbdut2iGAFHgrkG2nHpl2TTbrkl20klI5JkvAFgBgnTbQv8D)

Does not use prime factors. Expects a nonnegative integer and returns the coefficients lowest (constant) to highest.

### How?

Uses binary representation. Coefficient 0 encoded in bits (least significant to most) 1,3,5,7,9,... coefficient 1 encoded in bits 2,6,10,14,..., coefficient 2 encoded in bits 4,12,20,28,..., etc. The bits are simply read as a binary number except that the lsb encodes the sign (more precisely, the presence or absence of a tilde operator i.e. 0 <-> -1, 1 <-> -2, etc. Advantage over "naive" `-`: no redundancy at 0.)

Comment: No need for the `or[0]` if you just stipulate there are no trailing zero coefficients.

Comment: I just wasn't sure whether it is ok to represent 0 by an empty coefficient list. I guess one could argue either way. Or is there some relevant meta I'm not aware of?

Comment: You are already representing a polynomial as a list of coefficients without trailing zeros (i.e. \$3x^2\$ is `[0,0,3]` rather than `[0,0,3,0,0,...,0,...]`), so there should be no need to special case the zero polynomial.

Comment: @JonathanAllan By the same token one could argue that base 10 (or anything) integers are represented without leading zeros, yet, for example, Python does not accept the empty string to represent 0.

Answer (score 7):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 10 bytes

```
Ňƒ$ƥ←2EƂ∙ŋ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FpuPth-bpHJs6aO2CUauRk6POmYe7V5SnJRcDJWHqQMA)

The zero polynomial is represented by `0`, and other polynomials are represented by an ascending list of coefficients. For example, `x^2 + 2x + 3` is represented by `[3, 2, 1]`.

```
Ňƒ$ƥ←2EƂ∙ŋ
Ň              Choose a natural number n
 ƒ$ƥ←2EƂ∙      Compute the array of exponents of n's prime factorization.
               This is basically Jelly's ÆE operator
         ŋ     Optionally negate each nonzero element
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>10</s>  8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

```
ÆENḂ¡€:2
```

A monadic Link that accepts a positive integer, \$n\$, and yields the \$n^{\text{th}}\$ integer polynomial as a list of coefficients for increasing powers of \$x\$ with no trailing zeros (i.e. `[0, 0, 2, 0, -5]` represents \$-5x^4+2x^2\$, and `[]` represents \$0\$)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//w4ZFTuG4gsKh4oKsOjL/w4fFkuG5mClZ//8xMDA)**

#### How?

```
ÆENḂ¡€:2 - Link: n
ÆE       - prime factor exponents e.g. n=3*3*7*7*7 -> [0,2,0,3]
     €   - for each {exponent value, e}:
    ¡    -   repeat...
   Ḃ     -   ...number of times: modulo 2 {e} -> 1 if e is odd else 0
  N      -   ...action: negate
      :2 - integer divide by two (vectorises)
```

This gives the same order as the example sequence, just with negated coefficients.

Comment: Can you not vectorise `-1ᵉe` to avoid having to use `€`?

Comment: Yes, but it's the same byte count (unless I've missed a trick of course) since it will need the `ÆE` result on both sides: `ÆE-*×Ɗ:2`.

Answer (score 6):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 11 bytes

```
_2#._#:@q:]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT0F9TQFWysFdR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxOt5IWS9e2cqh0CoWIrJRkys1OSPfIU3NTsFQO1PP2AAivmABhAYA)

The first half (using prime factorization exponents) is stolen from existing solutions, but the second half is new I guess. To convert "all integers >= 0" to "all integers", I use the [negabinary](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Negabinary.html) system. That is, convert each nonnegative integer to base 2 and then interpret the binary sequence as base -2. This is shorter in J than doing a "divmod 2".

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ÆEBḅ-2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm6vTwx2tukb/D7cfnfRw5wzNyP//DQ0MAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḟıDu@×;2÷
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOCU5RiVDNCVCMUR1JTQwJUMzJTk3JTNCMiVDMyVCNyZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTUmZmxhZ3M9)
or [verify a few more cases](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSVDNCVCMSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOCU5RiVDNCVCMUR1JTQwJUMzJTk3JTNCMiVDMyVCNyZmb290ZXI9JTNCJUMyJUI2aiZpbnB1dD0xMCZmbGFncz0=)

Port of Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer.

*-1 thanks to @Neil*

##### Explanation

```python
ḟıDu@×;2÷  # Implicit input
ḟ          # Prime factor exponents
 ı    ;    # Map over this list:
  D        #  Duplicate current number
   u@      #  -1 ** that
     ×     #  Multiply by the number
       2÷  # Floor divide each by 2
           # Implicit output
```

Comment: The `d` is unnecessary. (Jelly seems to need it because it can't easily negate `x` `x` times.)

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks @Neil

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>56</s> <s>53</s> <s>51</s> 31 bytes

```
≔ＩＥ⮌⍘Ｎ²ιθＷθ«≔Φι﹪λ²θ⟦Ｉ↨⮌Φι¬﹪λ²±²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9La9xAEITP9q/Y4yw40I@ZfpBTYjDk4MUkx5CD4oi1QNm1V1rnEPLb5ZIxSWBmpJ7pr6rr/qE73R@7cVk@TNOwP5TrbprLbfdYPvfP/Wnqy8du6r/Mp@GwL58Oj@d5d/75vT@V7dVGtjgG7Kft@8tfD8PYb8rTdvP78uJN62YYZ7QOV5vb44/zeCzjG7QCF3fQnMvXV8PV5K/jP2x3xCz/oyu86/fd3Je1@gadP8sSGVGtmVdlbp5Nw1BLw1/WxqJmQa9dkdXRoxKm5tyoUvMIM1VPEsdFcEPZqkDFWEgdMFMzwk7NVHzMQAmqCtFKLhTwlmrAIKucrk4WkeLhyWyhriwpVRrDG@MQTIyZgvFOtdVwqmoIoU1UU9mlCUujphpwJ@XakuGH8QkaTGtmvAJ1RI6aaim69kTlUFpjCyUuK5azhxgCZS7vnscX) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the `0`-indexed `n`th polynomial (lowest degree first). Explanation:

```
≔ＩＥ⮌⍘Ｎ²ιθ
```

Input `n` and convert it to base `2`. (Note that if an empty output is acceptable for the zero polynomial, then `≔⮌↨Ｎ²θ` would suffice, saving 3 bytes.)

```
Ｗθ«
```

Repeat until there are no more terms of the polynomial.

```
≔Φι﹪λ²θ
```

Remove the current term from the value.

```
⟦Ｉ↨⮌Φι¬﹪λ²±²
```

Extract the current term from the previous value and convert it from negabinary for output.

<s>114</s> <s>111</s> <s>109</s> 87 bytes to pretty-print the output:

```
≔⮌↨Ｎ²θＷθ«⊞υ↨⮌Φθ¬﹪λ²±²≔Φθ﹪λ²θ»∨Φ⪫⮌Ｅυ⎇ι⁺⎇∨¬κ⊖↔ι﹪%+dι§ +-ι⎇κ⁺x⎇⊖κ⍘κ”y⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹”ωωωω∨κ⁻+ι0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDbattAEH2Ov0IICiuswM7OXsmTSymkYDe0/QHFXmwRRYp1SVJKH/RHpfe8@lP0I@6sYuMUpJFm9txml5usXlZZsd/PmiZfl@yDv/d149nrjMplede1i@722tcsSSORUNkmF5OHTV74iG2T6Mvk7KprNqxLo5FxpL/Ni5ZI2zRaVC2bV6uuqFgxSgSRhV9nrWehu5icHaxPnP/wz5ZfJ1d1XrbsfX3EvavyU9x5dhcyfPJ1mdWfWZ5GV0XXsGNPrJDjhsTe@GXtb33Z@hWbXTdV0VGQfEx1sI1fTVdxGuU0mbWX5co/sjiano@j5ORxc/CIH@PT8KV6cAuX8rGl5OuAj4f@2@5p9333Y@h/Dv2vof899H@G/u/QP8WEfkhelLGmEUUn5jwvg9X0OQSNYx7T3e331lkrtdJGIoAyTqHV1AtFf04qEKi15SPKOmkIg8Jq1AYUl1wZa7VGNI4LQwMLilolBaloEBwNkYErzel16BzSR2tiCeokiUpuBLfkLaQmGskiOIOGa2udMNY4AG3RIAgnpFBA3hSHk4kG4BbonEslreESNS2BSiA6BCOUAKG4QrTkzhGkckB@FJ@TBvCwM50S1dDKVjrUTmDAWAkWeVhbcEdDSY8BY4WmhZzbn98X/wA) Link is to verbose version of code. Pretty-prints the `0`-indexed `n`th polynomial. Explanation:

```
≔⮌↨Ｎ²θ
```

Input `n` and convert it to base `2`. (Note that if an empty output is acceptable for the zero polynomial, then `≔⮌↨Ｎ²θ` would suffice, saving 3 bytes.)

```
Ｗθ«
```

Repeat until there are no more terms of the polynomial.

```
⊞υ↨⮌Φθ¬﹪λ²±²
```

Extract the current term from the previous value and convert it from negabinary.

```
≔Φθ﹪λ²θ
```

Remove the current term from the value.

```
»∨Φ⪫⮌Ｅυ⎇ι⁺⎇∨¬κ⊖↔ι﹪%+dι§ +-ι⎇κ⁺x⎇⊖κ⍘κ”y⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹”ωωωω∨κ⁻+ι0
```

Pretty-print the polynomial. (And I think this must be the first time I've used 4 `ω`s in a row!)

Edit: Now uses @loopywalt's encoding and @Bubbler's negabinary trick.

Answer (score 3):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate) `-a`, 35 bytes

```
|-?[1-9][0-9]*(,(0|-?[1-9][0-9]*))*
```

Generates polynomials infinitely, given as lists of coefficients from highest to lowest degree. E.g. `1,-2,3` represents \$x^2-2x+3\$. The first result is the empty string, representing \$0\$.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdVm0km6iUuyCpaUlaboWN5VrdO2jDXUtY6MNgISWho6GAaqIpqYWRClUxwIoDQA)

#### Explanation

Iterating over countable sets is basically Regenerate's whole thing, although since it's designed for generating strings, its number-handling is a bit primitive.

```
|-?[1-9][0-9]*(,(0|-?[1-9][0-9]*))*
|                                    Either the result is empty, or:
 -?[1-9][0-9]*                       Lead with a nonzero coefficient:
 -?                                   Possibly negative
   [1-9]                              Starts with a nonzero digit
        [0-9]*                        Continues with 0 or more additional digits
              (                  )*  Continue with zero or more further coefficients:
               ,                      Comma to separate from previous coefficient
                (0|             )     Either the coefficient is 0, or it's nonzero:
                   -?                  Possibly negative
                     [1-9]             Starts with a nonzero digit
                          [0-9]*       Continues with 0 or more additional digits
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 242 bytes:

```py
def f(n):
 d,D={},{}
 while n>1:
  k=0
  for i in range(2,n+1):
   if all(i%j for j in range(2,i)if i!=j):
    k+=1;D[i]=k
    if 0==n%i:d[i]=d.get(i,0)+1;n//=i
 return'+'.join(f'{(abs(T:=d[j])//2+1*T%2)*[-1,1][T%2]}*x^{D[j]-1}'for j in d)
```

Returns a pretty-printed polynomial for \$n\$.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU9Na4QwED3XXzE9iInJrsZeyi7pyX8hFixJdifKKKmlLeJvt3EXSulleF8D703f83Wkp@cpbJuxDhwjfkrAyFovq1zWBD6vOFigFxVl6HUZrxsDICBB6OhiWSVJqP0LAB10w8Aw9beQ/xtCHl181P4ehV5oda4bbHV/49EttaYUT2YXzfFiZ4ay5EKdqSg0JhDs/BEoE9nRj0jMZQvr3t6ZaXzLi6ISKt9hWvG8OSip2uZO2zX/el3qiA9qzX6LGb79W6IkqDLWe5gC0swcQ863Hw)

Comment: suggest getting rid of `if i!=j` in line 6 as `j` < `i`

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 36 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.5 bytes

```
∆ǏÞnİ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJyPSIsIiIsIuKIhsePw55uxLAiLCIiLCI3Il0=)

Ports jelly with a few vyxal specific things.

*-15 bits/-1.875 bytes from Bubbler pointing out that `Þn` exists*

### Explained

```
∆ǏÞnİ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
∆Ǐ     # ‎⁡To each prime factor exponent from the input
    İ  # ‎⁢get the exponent-th item of
  Þn   # ‎⁣an infinite list of all the integers (positive and negative - 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, ...)
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: `∆ǏƛÞni` Why calculate when you have the necessary thing built-in :P

Comment: @Bubbler well you see that's because I forgot it existed :p

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 260 bytes

Port of [@loopy walt's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263217/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZDBTsJAEIZj4qlPMRfIjFJckIOptIkJFxPrhXgiYLali2vKQnYXE4U-iRcueNIH0qdx2wYJcQ6z_-z882V33j9MynN-uf1aJM9ZaiHmUsF6t7LCv_o5OZ1mAgbIg1tlW0mZKZQCkUes2UwiRpsN8n6p-4yIXySQ5SYDZ-GNJAzZ4coJv-OVuPgYh6WVzhNqJFVboKkawZ00duTUODQw5zZ9WqfcgVgY3cv8utKPYYQxmpbfpYnGgVM9IgoCgXXVdVVRUfWe6tI_HvujxdXQBLtnB1xRL-P7E6Akzd2CkOuZCeBGa_46Glot1WxMATwoaSGEtQcuxEKjgr4PDFbKyhx6jGDprDZXKFARVbYXnsPU_VSq1JY_Ng6A-5EOc0HtOV-ioLZdDDNbDe0xR4NtI9-yElp4hVe_ebutz18)

```scala
def D(a:Int,b:Int)=if((a>0&&b>0)||(a<0&&b<0))a/b else if(a%b==0)a/b else a/b-1
def M(a:Int,b:Int)=((a%b)+b)%b
def f(s:Int):List[Int]=s match{case 0=>Nil;case _=>(M(s,-2)^r(D(s,4)))::f(r(D(s,2)))}
def r(s:Int):Int=s match{case 0=>0;case _=>M(s,2)^(2*r(D(s,4)))}
```

Ungolfed  version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVLBTsJAEE088hXvItkVigU5GENJTLyYiBfiiaDZlhbWlC3pLiQo3P0HL170o_waZ7c0BSI9bGdn5s17MzufPzoSqbj6-vpemsS7_j37yMLXODIYCKnwXgMmcYLF2swydSdXTNzgXpkmQvfn7kTgEgGZgDGBPnzU6witwbHZgHy90kcG5xC4ROgwcapjBxQ4p3AQWMxR2F3hoU2ube1A0yCbnNLEipIcDXuQVSITpsvMB6nNiMwx5WvMhYlmu14iQcQ-gj4eZVp5XqzHoljFr5vwOhzPyFk1KHJ2OXXaaBDfUaBDgf1W8kpQIf2UFP9IyIEGJ4F1cPGfjn26OT0tE_mUSG_zXKxHQ5NLNR0T_ZOS1XMmWc4Ueh5xL5WRKbr0NAtKNaliCVOuKrASKSY0EakiYyej7exLSNunj7fmYsES3jLZMDYOVJY5ALa0fIsLqdtasZC7vSz38w8)

```scala
object Main {
  def pythonDiv(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
    if ((a > 0 && b > 0) || (a < 0 && b < 0)) a / b
    else if (a % b == 0) a / b
    else a / b - 1
  }

  def pythonMod(a: Int, b: Int): Int = ((a % b) + b) % b

  def f(s: Int): List[Int] = s match {
    case 0 => Nil
    case _ => List(pythonMod(s, -2) ^ r(pythonDiv(s, 4))) ++ f(r(pythonDiv(s, 2)))
  }

  def r(s: Int): Int = s match {
    case 0 => 0
    case _ => pythonMod(s, 2) ^ (2 * r(pythonDiv(s, 4)))
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    for(n <- 0 until 40) println(f(n))
    val distinctLists = (0 until 10000).map(f).toSet
    println(distinctLists.size)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 96 bytes

```haskell
import Data.List
f=nub$(dropWhile(==0))<$>concatMap(\n->(iterate(map(:)[-n..n]<*>)[[]])!!n)[0..]
```

`iterate(map(:)[-n..n]<*>)[[]]!!n` gets us {−*n*, …, *n*}*ⁿ*. Then we drop leading zeros and let `nub` do all the hard work.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWNxMycwvyi0oUXBJLEvV8MotLuNJs80qTVDRSivILwjMyc1I1bG0NNDVtVOyS8_OSE0t8Ews0YvJ07TQyS1KLEktSNXKBAlaa0bp5enp5sTZadprR0bGxmoqKeZrRBnp6sRB7duUmZuYp2CoUFGXmlSioKJQkZqcqmBoAWWkQBTAHAQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 49 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,i=0)=>n?n&1?f(n/2,(i<1)-i):[i,...f(n>>1)]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBDkAwEADA38huVKkb1XqIOAitrMiulPh@uU4yx/Iu95roeiqWLeQcHbAi16DzPHJhxghctwpoMFgR9hMprfWP3huc@2nONkqCf1ga2tDZsiRchW85gz5lhwiEaPMH)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 52 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,i=0)=>n?n&1?f(n/2,i+1):[n&2?~i:i,...f(n>>2)]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBCoAgEADA38QumpVHRX1IdIjK2IjdqOjY163rwGzjM17TScdds8xLKTkAawothsiJqy5l4MZqUh26niubXnKkjTG/x2hxcP1QfJYT/uS9UoST8CX7YnZZIQMh@vIB)

Write index into binary and convert `x011111` into one coefficient

zero is expressed as `00` so needn't extra check of remaining

Answer (score 0):

## [BQN (CBQN)](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 55 bytes

```
{↑⍷∾{{⊑(=0)⊐0}⊸↓¨∾{⥊([⥊(↕)≍(-↕)])∾⌜⍟⋈⟨⟩}¨↕}¨↕+2}
```

This is a port of my Haskell answer. It's extremely slow.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704qTBvwYKlpSVpuhY3Gx81LArOyC-v_jB36spHbRMf9W5_1LGvuvpR10QNkJCtgeajrgkGtY-6djxqm3xoBUjy0dIujWgQ8ahtKkiN5qPOXg1dGCdWE6jmUc-cR73zwWZ2dzyav-LR_JW1QM0QJQiWtlGtCcQhUPfA3AUA)