ZigZag encoding and decoding
ZigZag encoding is a method of encoding signed integers to unsigned integers. Non-negative integers are multiplied by two. Negative integers are equal to their absolute values multiplied by two, minus one. Decoding is the inverse process.

(Viotti, Juan & Kinderkhedia, Mital. (2022). A Survey of JSON-compatible Binary Serialization Specifications. arXiv.2201.02089. CC BY 4.0)
Write two programs or functions: One which takes a signed integer and ZigZag encodes it, and another which decodes a ZigZag-encoded integer. Your program or function should be able to accommodate the largest number types your language or platform supports.
This is code-golf. Your score is the combined number of bytes of your two programs or functions. Lowest score wins.
Rules

Default I/O rules and standard rules apply. Standard loopholes are forbidden.

Test cases
Decoded Encoded
  -10      19
   -3       5
   -1       1
    0       0
    1       2
    3       6
   10      20


Sandbox

Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/93441/85334

May we invert (signed integer) signs or index (unsigned integers) from 1?

@att No, sorry.

Jelly, 4 + 6 5 3 = 7 bytes
Encoder:
Ḥ»~$

Try it online!
Ḥ       Double the input.
 »      Take the maximum of that and
   $    its
  ~     bitwise NOT. (-1-n)

Decoder:
~¡H

Try it online!
-1 and inspiration for another -1 thanks to Jonathan Allan
Full program only. Try it modified for a test harness!
~      Bitwise NOT the input
 ¡     a number of times equal to itself.
  H    Halve that result.


R, 36 34 bytes
Encoder, 18 bytes
\(n)abs(n)*2-(n<0)

Attempt This Online!
Or
\(n)2*max(n,-n-.5)

Attempt This Online!
Decoder, 18 16 bytes
\(n)n%/%2-n%%2*n

Attempt This Online!

Japt, 8 7 5 + 5 = 13 12 10 bytes
Encoder
Ñ
w~U

Try it (includes all test cases)
Ñ\nw~U     :Implicit input of integer U
Ñ          :Multiply by 2
 \n        :Reassign to U
   w       :Maximum with
    ~U     :  Bitwise NOT of U

Decoder
Ï¶U}c

Try it (includes all test cases
Ï¶U}c     :Implicit input of integer U
Ï         :Function taking a 0-based iteration index as argument
 ¶U       :  Is equal to U
   }      :End function
    c     :Get the first integer from the sequence [0,-1,1,-2,2,-3,3,...] that returns true


So you encode with "Ñ aUgUa", a variant of Spanish agua. Interesting fluid coding.

Set Theory: The Language, 3+3 = 6 bytes*
Encode
Flags: -iℤ -oℕ
↣ℤℕ

Decode
Flags: -iℕ -oℤ
↣ℕℤ

Explanation
In STTL, everything is represented as a mathematical set. For normal operations to work, they use "universes", a sort of context. The function ↣ "inject" is biversal, i.e. it uses two universes. ℕ refers to the naturals universe and ℤ to the integers universe. So the encoder ↣ℤℕ injects integers onto naturals, which follows the challenge requirement and more importantly the usual ℕ ↔ ℤ bijection in mathematics. ↣ℕℤ is required to form a bijection with ↣ℤℕ, and therefore does the inverse operation (casting a natural to an integer is done with → "convert").
Running
Save the code to files and run sttl encode.sttl -iℤ -oℕ <number> and sttl decode.sttl -iℕ -oℤ <number>. Remember that negative numbers have to be inputted with ¯ to not make it think it's flags.
Scoring
The flags are purely for nicer IO. The two programs are standalone: if you input the natural representation for sets (which is defined as such: 0 → ∅; n + 1 → n ∪ {n}) to the decoder you get the result as the integer representation of sets (which is defined as a pair of naturals as defined above, to be interpreted by subtracting their meanings; pairs are defined as (a, b) → {{a}, {a, b}}); the opposite applies for encoder.

Cool language, but are these functions or snippets?

debatable, there is no way to define functions currently

@noodleperson probably fixed

I don't think it's valid still because we count programs that must be ran with flags as different languages than without flags, and I assume the encoder and decoder are supposed to be in the same language

hmm, that's a good point, though it doesn't really say they have to be in the same language

@noodleperson maybe let's move to chat to figure out what to do

K (ngn/k), 10+6 = 16 bytes
Encoder:
|/(-1-)\2*

Decoder:
-1/!-:

Try it online!
        2*  double
  (-1-)\    and its bitnot
|/          max

   !-:      range -x...-1
-1/         convert from base -1


iogii 12 bytes
encoder 6
2*:~(X

2* dup negate pred max

Try it
Max of 2* thing and its complement as others have done
decoder 6
}~b#1~

countTo negate backwards fromBase 1 negate

Try it
Based on att's K solution
Test suite

Halfwit, 17 16 12 (5.5+6.5) bytes
Encoder:
+?><l[n+N

-4 bytes thanks to emanresuA.
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Decoder:
(>M<+N;>{</

Try it online or verify all test cases.
This language feels as inefficient as I remember. 
Explanation:
+                # Add the (implicit) input-bigint to itself to double it
 ?               # Push the input again
  ><             # Push compressed 0
    l            # Check if the input is smaller than 0
     [           # If it is indeed negative:
      n+         #  Add 1
        N        #  And then negate it
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly)

(                # Loop the (implicit) input-bigint amount of times:
 >M<             #  Push compressed integer 1
    +            #  Add it to the current bigint
                 #  (which uses the implicit input-bigint in the first iteration)
     N           #  Then negate it
      ;>{<       # After the loop: push compressed 2
          /      # Integer-divide
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly)


Oh hey it's that awful language I made two years ago! +?><l[n+N saves four bytes on the encoder.

@emanresuA Thanks! Pretty stupid of me to not use + instead of >{<*. I didn't knew about n being 1 outside of loops though, so thanks for the ?><l[n+N portion. :)

I guess my original approach with the >{<* replaced with + and both >M< replaced with n would have worked for 9 characters as well, but it's -2.5 bytes instead of -4. :)

05AB1E, 10 8 (4+4) bytes
Encoder:
·D±M

Try it online or verify all test cases.
Decoder:
F±};

-2 bytes porting the decoder of @UnrelatedString's Jelly answer, so make sure to upvote that answer as well!
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Original decoder (6 bytes):
±‚;ʒ.ï

Outputs as a singleton.
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
·      # Double the (implicit) input-integer
 D     # Duplicate this
  ±    # Take the bitwise-NOT of the copy: -n-1
   M   # Push a copy of the maximum value of the stack
       # (which is output implicitly as result)

F      # Loop the (implicit) input-integer amount of times:
 ±     #  Take the bitwise-NOT: -n-1
       #  (which uses the implicit input-integer in the first iteration)
  };   # After the loop: halve the result
       # (which is output implicitly as result)

±      # Take the bitwise-NOT of the (implicit) input-integer
 ‚     # Pair it with the (implicit) input-integer
  ;    # Halve each
   ʒ   # Filter this pair by:
    .ï #  Is it an integer?
       # (after which the resulting singleton is output implicitly)


JavaScript (ES6), 23 bytes
-6 thanks to @Neil
-1 thanks to @m90
Encoder (12 bytes)
n=>n*2^n>>31

Try it online!
Decoder (11 bytes)
n=>n/2^-n%2

Try it online!

n=>n/2^-n%2 for the decoder.

n=>n*2^-(n<0) for the encoder.

A further improvement to the encoder is n=>n*2^n>>31. (Because the bitwise operations already convert their arguments to 32-bit integers, this doesn't reduce the validity range.)

APL+WIN, 13 + 17 = 30 bytes
Index origin = 0
Encoder:- Prompts for integer
(0⌊×n)+2×|n←⎕

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic
Decoder:- Prompts for integer
1 ¯1[2|n]×⌈.5×n←⎕

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

Go, 107 bytes
func e(a int)int{o:=a*2;if a<0{o=(-a)*2-1};return o}
func d(a int)int{o:=a/2;if a%2>0{o=-(a+1)/2};return o}

Attempt This Online!
e encodes, and d decodes.

C (gcc), 22 + 19 = 41 bytes
e(n){n=(n*=2)<0?~n:n;}d(n){n=-(n&1)^n/2;}

Try it online!

Vyxal 3, 5 + 5 = 10 bytes
Encoder: (Vyxal It Online!)
ÞṬN$Ḟ

Decoder: (Vyxal It Online!)
ÞṬN$i

Explanation of the encoder:
ÞṬN$Ḟ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
   $Ḟ  # ‎⁡The index of the input in:
ÞṬ     # ‎⁢  The set of integers (0, 1, -1, 2, -2, ...)
  N    # ‎⁣  Negated (0, -1, 1, -2, 2, ...)

The decoder works the same way, except with indexing instead of finding the index.

Raku, 14 + 27 = 41 bytes
Encoder:
.abs*2-($_ <0)

Attempt This Online!
Decoder:
($_/2).ceiling*(1-2*($_%2))

Attempt This Online!
Encoder: take 2 times the absolute value then maybe subtract 1 depending on negativity.
Decoder: do ceil-division then determine the sign over evenness.

Python, encoder 22 bytes, decoder 19 bytes
e=lambda x:max(x+x,~x-x)
d=lambda x:x//2-x%2*x

Attempt This Online!
Python, encoder 22 bytes, decoder 23 bytes
e=lambda x:max(x+x,~x-x)
d=lambda x:[x,-x][x&1]>>1

Attempt This Online!

decoder 18 bytes

Google Sheets, 17 + 24 = 41 bytes
Encoder
=2*abs(A1)-(A1<0)

Decoder
=int(B1/(2-4*isodd(B1)))



x86 32-bit machine code, 6 + 7 = 13 bytes
99 D1 E0 31 D0 C3
D1 E8 19 D2 31 D0 C3

Try it online!
Uses the regparm(1) calling convention – argument in EAX, result in EAX.
In assembly:
e:  cdq             # Sign-extend EAX into EDX:EAX.
                    #  This sets every bit of EDX to the sign bit of EAX.
    shl eax, 1      # Shift EAX left by 1 bit.
    xor eax, edx    # Exclusive-or EAX with EDX.
                    #  This inverts all bits if the sign bit was 1.
                    #  (In two's complement notation, that turns n into -n-1.)
                    #  x becomes 2x if nonnegative, -2x-1 if negative.
    ret             # Return.

d:  shr eax, 1      # Shift EAX right by 1 bit. The low bit goes into CF.
    sbb edx, edx    # Subtract EDX+CF from EDX, so it becomes -CF.
    xor eax, edx    # Exclusive-or EAX with EDX.
                    #  This inverts all bits if the low bit was 1.
                    #  2n becomes n; 2n+1 becomes -n-1.
    ret             # Return.


This can be reduced to 10 bytes by providing the two functions together and sharing code, if that is allowed:
D1 E8 EB 01 C0 19 D2 31 D0 C3

Try it online!
The decoding function starts at the beginning, and the encoding function starts after the first 3 bytes.
In assembly:
d:  shr eax, 1      # Shift EAX right by 1 bit. The low bit goes into CF.
    .byte 0xEB      # This byte and the next form JMP with displacement +1,
                    #  jumping to the SBB instruction.
e:  .byte 0x01      # This byte and the next form 'add eax, eax'.
    .byte 0xC0      #  The value of EAX is doubled. The high bit goes into CF.
    sbb edx, edx    # Subtract EDX+CF from EDX, so it becomes -CF.
    xor eax, edx    # Exclusive-or EAX with EDX.
    ret             # Return.


So basically the encoder could be the same as the decoder, except with the r changed to an l? I guess it makes sense, as you're moving that bit, while all the other bits get flipped if it was a 1 bit.

J, 8+10=18 bytes
Both functions use the same formulas as pajonk's R sol.
Encoder, 8 bytes
+:@|-<&0

Attempt This Online!
+:@|-<&0
     <&0   NB. less than 0?
+:@|       NB. absolute value(|) then(@) double(+:)
    -      NB. subtraction

Decoder, 10 bytes
<.@-:-+:|]

Attempt This Online!
<.@-:-+:|]
         ]   NB. input
      +:     NB. double the input
        |    NB. mod
<.@-:        NB. halve(-:) then(@) floor(<.), aka integer division
     -       NB. subtraction


Charcoal, 22 18 bytes
Encoder, 10 bytes
ＮθＩ⁻⊗↔θ‹θ⁰

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @doubleunary and @pajonk's encoders.
Decoder, 12 8 bytes
Ｉ↨…±Ｎ⁰±¹

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @att's decoder.

Math, 19 + 33 = 52 bytes
Encoder:
Actual Source:
f(x)={x<0:-2x-1,2x}

Formatted Latex:
$$
f(x)=\{x<0:-2x-1,2x\}
$$
Decoder:
Actual Source:
g(x)={0<=mod(x,2)<1:x/2,(x+1)/-2}

Formatted Latex:
$$
g(x)=\{0\le mod(x,2):x/2,(x+1)/2)\}
$$
Link to Desmos
*Desmos requires quite verbose latex code, so the formatted latex can't be directly copied into Desmos. I counted the equation in the actual source for determining my byte count.

Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! We require solutions to be full programs or functions - in desmos's case, functions, so you should prepend a f(x)= to each of these. You probably want to include the actual source code as well as formatted latex, and you might want to include a https://www.desmos.com/calculator link to demonstrate this. Also, the code that you copy out of desmos is quite verbose - we have a tips for golfing in desmos page that includes tricks to shorten things.

What you should count is the length of the source code that can be pasted into desmos - in this case, that's f(x)=\{x<0:-2x-1,2x\} and g(x)=\{0<=\mod(x,2)<1:x/2,(x+1)/-2\} with a leading newline on both (see this for why)

Will do when I have time

AWK, 21+23=44 bytes
Encoder
$0=$1>=0?2*$1:-2*$1-1

Try it online!
Decoder
$0=$1%2?-($1+1)/2:$1/2

Try it online!
Unified 48 bytes
$0=$1~/e/?$2>=0?2*$2:-2*$2-1:$2%2?-($2+1)/2:$2/2

Try it online!
Combined example: awk -f zigzag.awk <<< "d 19" or "e -10" for decode/encode respectively.

Can you save any bytes by splitting this into two programs instead of testing for d/e?

Thank you, updated it with the split.
